# Nginx redirect based on user agent

Tags: nginx

Here is my current nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 90;
  server_name www.domain.com www.domain2.com;
  root /root/app;
  location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  location ~ /([-\w]+)/(\w+)/ {
    proxy_pass bla bla
  }
}
```

it works fine, both `www.domain.com` and `www.domain2.com` serve the same content.

now I'd like to add

> if the user is visiting www.domain.com and the user agent is xxx then redirect to www.domain2.com

I've searched and tried a lot of method but none of them works.

Comment: Do you still want to serve the same content, even after the redirect?

Comment: @Pothi yes, exactly

Comment: Ok. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are Two ways to fix this issue.

1. Have two seperate "server" blocks for www.domain.com & www.domain2.com and add the following lines of rules to "server" block www.domain.com. This is recommended way to solve this issue.

   ```
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^xxx$") {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 permanent;
   }
   ```
2. If you want to manage the redirect with a single "server" block for both domains, Try below rules

   ```
   set $check 0;
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^xxx$") {
       set $check 1;
   }
   if ($host ~* ^www.domain.com$) {
       set $check "${check}1";
   }
   if ($check = 11) {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 permanent;
   }
   ```

Comment: Direct quote from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ ... "The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are: return and rewrite".

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Have two server blocks, one each for domain.com and domain2.com.

Step 2: [Use if correctly](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) as it is evil if used incorrectly.

Here's the complete solution...

```
server {
  listen 90;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  root /root/app;

  # redirect if 'xxx' is found on the user-agent string
  if ( $http_user_agent ~ 'xxx' ) {
    return 301 http://www.domain2.com$request_uri;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  location ~ /([-\w]+)/(\w+)/ {
    proxy_pass bla bla
  }
}

server {
  listen 90;
  server_name www.domain2.com;
  root /root/app;
  location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  location ~ /([-\w]+)/(\w+)/ {
    proxy_pass bla bla
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of 301, you may use 302 too, depending on your use-case.

Comment: hmm, I think this solution contains too many duplicating codes

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve an issue. I posted my solution only to make you to see the logic behind how it could be solved. There are multiple ways to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

The recommended way would probably be using a [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html), also because these variables are evaluated only when they are used.

Also the use of `return 301 ...` is preferred over rewrites, because no regular expression have to be compiled.

Here an example of where host and user-agent as a concatenated string are compared to a single regex:

```
map "$host:$http_user_agent" $my_domain_map_host {
  default                      0;
  "~*^www.domain.com:Agent.*$" 1;
}

server {
  if ($my_domain_map_host) {
    return 302 http://www.domain2.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

And this could be even more flexible, for example if a there not 2 but more domains involved.

Here we map `www.domain.com` with user-agents starting with `Agent` to `http://www.domain2.com` and `www.domain2.com` with the exact user-agent `Other Agent` to `http://www.domain3.com`:

```
map "$host:$http_user_agent" $my_domain_map_host {
  default                             0;
  "~*^www.domain.com:Agent.*$"        http://www.domain2.com;
  "~*^www.domain2.com:Other Agent$"   http://www.domain3.com;
}

server {
  if ($my_domain_map_host) {
    return 302 $my_domain_map_host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

**NB** you will need nginx 0.9.0 or higher for the concatenated string in map to work.